# Sort a json data with respect to user input

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I want to sort a json data using javascript, **the condition is user will enter a input value and based on the input value occurrence in json array I want to display a output**.
for example: If user input is **userInput ="Man"** & the json data is

```
var objs = [ 
{ first_nm: 'Mango raw'},
{ first_nm: 'Devgad Mango'},
{ first_nm: 'Mantra santra'},
{ first_nm: 'Prag Mango'},
{ first_nm: 'Pirate aam Mango'}];
```

The output list should be displayed as

1. first_nm: 'Mango raw'
2. first_nm: 'Mantra santra'
3. first_nm: 'Devgad Mango'
4. first_nm: 'Prag Mango'
5. first_nm: 'Pirate aam Mango'

I have tries to use compare function but it sorts a record in ascending order not with respect to user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to go through the list of strings and make a new array full of the strings that start with the user input. Then we can sort the matches and append the array of none matching strings to this list.

```js
var users = [{
    name: 'Devgad Mango'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mantra santra'
  },
  {
    name: 'Prag Mango'
  },
  {
    name: 'Pirate aam Mango'
  }, {
    name: 'Mango raw'
  },
];

function search(input) {
  const matches = [];
  const remeinder = [];
  users.forEach(user => {
    user.name.startsWith(input) ?
      matches.push(user) :
      remeinder.push(user);
  });
  console.log(matches, remeinder)

  // now we sort the matches

  matches.sort((a, b) => {
    const aa = a.name.toLowerCase();
    const bb = b.name.toLowerCase();
    if (aa < bb) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (aa > bb) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  console.log(matches);

  // now we want to push the remeinders to the end of the sorted array.

  matches.push(...remeinder);

  console.log(matches);
}

search('Man')
```

Comment: But what if user gives input in lower case , the above solution is not working in that case